# (Pyinstaller) failed to create process

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я перерыл все сайты в надежде на то, что я смогу найти решение проблемы, из-за которой я не могу конвертировать `.py` в `.exe`. Уже переустановил `pefile`, `pyinstaller` и `pypiwin32` на новую версию, но это тоже не помогло. Что я могу сделать ещё?

- *Путь к* `python.exe`: *C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe*
- *Путь к* `pyinstaller-script.py`: *D:\Python34\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да уж, я неплохо попотел, но в принципе справился с работой. Всё, что я сделал, это просто плюнул на `pyinstaller` и использовал `cx_freezer`. Один гайд мне очень сильно помог мне справиться с проблемой: [https://overcoder.net/q/67404/как-я-могу-конвертировать-py-в-exe-для-python](https://overcoder.net/q/67404/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-py-%D0%B2-exe-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-python).